# close method of Tornado's WebsocketClientConnection doesn't invoke on_close method of Websocket Handler

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a WebsocketHandler like this:

```
class MyHandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.application.logger.info('WebSocket connection opened from %s', self.request.remote_ip)

    def on_close(self):
        self.application.logger.info('WebSocket connection closed')

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)
```

and I have some tests using pytest like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app(request):
    request.cls.app_fixture = create_app(TornadoConfig)


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("app")
class TestWebSocket(testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return self.app_fixture

    def setUp(self):
        super(TestWebSocket, self).setUp()
        server = httpserver.HTTPServer(self.app_fixture)
        self.socket, self.port = testing.bind_unused_port()
        server.add_socket(self.socket)

    def _mk_client(self):
        client = websocket_connect('ws://localhost:{}/ws/'.format(self.port))
        TestWebSocket.clients.append(client)
        return client

    @testing.gen_test
    def test_auto_complete(self):
       client = yield self._mk_client()
       client.write_message('test')
       response = yield client.read_message()

       assert response == 'test'

       client.close()
```

although I traced it and I'm sure that `close` method is called, but `client.close()` doesn't have any effect on `MyHandler` and `on_close` is never called!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used `ThreadPoolExecutor` to solve my problem
so I created a `thread_pool`:

```
thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
```

and wrote another method to close the client's connection:

```
def close_ws(self, client):
    client.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    self.close_future.set_result('done')
```

and at the end of my test method I did:

```
self.thread_pool.submit(self.close_ws, client)
yield self.close_future
```

Comment: It's not clear what the solution is, ``self.close_future`` where come from? where this code has to be inserted?

Answer (score 1):

`client.close()` *will* cause `MyHandler.on_close` to be called, but it hasn't yet, and when the test method returns it never gets a chance. If you want to make sure that `on_close` is called you must wait for `on_close` to be called instead of returning as soon as `client.close()` has returned. See for example Tornado's tests of the websocket functionality: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/43e23f977715396ce243c6cd7e3387abf2a2e4ee/tornado/test/websocket_test.py#L44

Comment: Thank you for your answer! now I get it why it didn't work but I still have no idea how to fix it.
can you tell me more about this ``Future`` and how can I use it to test my on_close method without changing it's functionality! in your example on_close calls set_result method of provided future but I don't want to change my application code and functionality.

Comment: Why do you care whether `on_close` has run? Does it have some observable side effect that you can wait for? Most tests don't worry about things like this and just let the garbage collector clean everything up. If you need the server to close the simplest solution may be to send a message to the server asking it to close from its side instead of closing from the client side.

Comment: I have no special reason. I just wanted to test my ``on_close`` and when it drove me crazy, I made a promise to myself to solve it :D so I came up with this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34049874/3654352, solution